# vue @click parameter not defined

Tags: vue.js

What I am doing wrong

I have this:

```html
<stepTitle number=1 @click.native="setStep(number)"  :class=" step === 1 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="Let's get started"/>
```

then in the methods:

```javascript
methods: {
        setStep: function (event) {

            // some code
        }
    }
```

and I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "number" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Here is the file

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <stepTitle number=1 @click.native="setStep(number)"  :class=" step === 1 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="Let's get started"/>
        <section-container></section-container>
        <stepTitle number=2  @click.native="setStep(number)" :class=" step === 2 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="PICK DATE & TIME"/>
        <section-container></section-container>
        <stepTitle number=3  @click.native="setStep(number)" :class=" step === 3 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="LOGIN/REGISTER"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    import stepTitle from './components/stepTitle.vue'
    import sectionContainer from './components/sectionContainer'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            stepTitle,
            sectionContainer
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                count: 0,
                step: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setStep: function (event) {

                // some code
            }
        }


    }
</script>


<style>
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400';
</style>
```

Comment: Can we see your whole component?  What's your ```data``` field look like?

Comment: I edited and add more info

Comment: Number is a property of another component?... Other sleptitle is other component, to you get value, create an props, type function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `number` a prop of `<stepTitle>` component? `number` is evaluated within the context of the parent component, not `<stepTitle>`; `number` is not defined on the parent component.

Since you've hard-coded the `number` prop, just do the same for the click handler:

```
<stepTitle number=1 @click.native="setStep(1)"/>
                                           ^
```

---

Here's a more programmatic way of doing it to remove as much duplication as possible in the template:

```js
data() {
  return {
    steps: [
      "Let's get started",
      "PICK DATE & TIME",
      "LOGIN/REGISTER",
    ],
    step: 0,
  };
}
```

```vue
<template v-for="(title, i) of steps">
  <stepTitle
    @click.native="setStep(i)"
    :class="step === i ? 'active' : 'un-active'"
    :title="title"
    :number="i + 1"   (Not sure if number is actually a prop; omit if necessary)
  />
  <section-container v-if="i !== steps.length - 1"/>
</template>
```

Comment: I was trying to define number once and then use 'number' instead of hard-coding it

Comment: But you *are* hard coding it? I think what you mean is you don't want to duplicate the number across the props of the component; in this situation it isn't helpful. You can't define "local variables" within the template. Either define all data describing every `<stepTitle>` in code then render it out using `v-for` (overkill IMO), or do what I suggested.

Comment: Yea it's is true no need for complications.

Answer (score 1):

You want your variable `number` to live in your component's `data`.

```
Vue.Component('matirials-component', {

  data: function() {
    number: 1
  }

  // the rest of your component code
})
```

We have now defined the variable `number` on the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

unless `number` is a property of another component you should not define that it in the element but rather in your data object. If it is a property of another component you would have it like `:number="number"`

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <stepTitle @click.native="setStep(number)"  :class=" step === 1 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="Let's get started"/>
        <section-container></section-container>
        <stepTitle  @click.native="setStep(number + 1)" :class=" step === 2 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="PICK DATE & TIME"/>
        <section-container></section-container>
        <stepTitle  @click.native="setStep(number + 2)" :class=" step === 3 ? 'active' : 'un-active' " title="LOGIN/REGISTER"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

in your script number would be defined a default value of 1

```
data() {
 return {
  number: 1,
 }
}
```